# Adding user_ids to each article(devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, model

I have a user model:

`devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_secure_password
  has_many :articles`

And my schema for `User` looks like:

`create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end`

Half of these are from the devise gem. So what I'm trying to accomplish is having each article have an author assigned to it(first_name + last_name).

My article model looks like:

```
belongs_to :topic
belongs_to :user

def author
  "#{self.user_id.first_name} #{self.user_id.last_name}"
end
```

And my actions in the article controller looks like:

```
def create
@article = Article.new(article_params)
@article.user = current_user
if @article.save
  #@article.user = session[:user_id]
  flash[:notice] = "Article has been uploaded"
  redirect_to(:action => "show", :id => @article.id)
else
  flash[:notice] = "Please fill in all fields."
  render("new")
end
end
```

And if I do `<p><%=@article.author%></p>` in my show view, it has an error that says undefined method - 'first_name'

How do I add authors to each article.

Comment: Also, I don't know if I should use `@article.user_id = current_user` in the create action.

Answer (score 0):

Use self.user.first_name instead of self.user_id.first_name.in your author method
And @article.user = current_user is fine if you want ot use user_id in this case then
use @artilce.user_id = current_user.id

Comment: Hi. I now have the problem of devise interfering with the original code I had. I have code in an `Access` controller:

Comment: `def attempt_login
  if params[:email].present? && params[:password].present?
          found_user = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first
       if found_user
        authorised_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
      end
    end
    if authorised_user
      session[:user_id] = authorised_user.id
      session[:email] = authorised_user.email
      flash[:notice] = "You are logged in"
      redirect_to(:controller => "articles", :action => 'index')
end`

Comment: I think its not related to your original problem.by the way can you explain the problem which you are facing now, because form this method and your comment i am not able to conclude anything...

Answer (score 0):

okay here is how you do it:

user.rb

```
has_many :items
```

article.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

articles_controller.rb

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article].permit(:name, ...))
    @article.user_id = current_user.id
    if @article.save  
        flash[:notice] = 'article created'
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```